# How to find the critical numbers for this?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I found the domain of this $$f\left( x\right) = e^\sqrt[3] {x}$$ which are the Reals.

but I need to the critical numbers of $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$

We calculate those derivatives to obtain :

$f'\left( x\right) =\dfrac{e^\sqrt[3]{x}}{3\sqrt[3] {x^{2}}}$

$f''\left( x\right) = \dfrac{\left( \sqrt[3] {x}-2\right) e^{\sqrt[3] {x}}}{9\sqrt[3] {x^{5}}}$

How do I find the critical numbers for $f'$ and $f''$?

For $f'(x) = 0$ I found no value x and when $f'(x) \nexists$ I found $x = 0$.

For $f''(x) = 0$ I found $x = 8$ and $f''(x) \nexists$ I found $x = 0$

Are they correct?

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Comment: What is $f'(x)\not\exists$?